# Exporting Geometry Nodes to Unity

Tags: unity, .fbx

I need to export a geometry node-generated tree from Blender to Unity with its wind animations, but each time if I export it as an FBX it exports with no animation. A USD export shows the animation, but Unity doesn't accept USD files.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258216/can-i-export-a-geometry-node-animation-to-an-fbx-in-3-1/258217#258217

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Probably not what you wanted to hear, but you're welcome! :^)

Comment: Yeah! ;D Thanks again!

Comment: I figured it out, and so this can be closed. Turns out you can't directly export blender objects to unity. (See link in comments for details.)